# Shutting down a Go server on browser close

Tags: go, shutdown

I wrote a small checkbook ledger in Go as a server that runs in localhost and opens the default browser to a small web app front-end (https://bitbucket.org/grkuntzmd/checks-and-balances).

To automatically shut down the server when the browser tab is closed, I have the browser call a "heartbeat" URL every few seconds. If that heartbeat does not arrive, the server uses [`(*Server) Shutdown`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown) to stop running.

Is there any way to do the same thing using contexts (https://golang.org/pkg/context/)? It is my understanding from watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSzR0VEraWw) episode of JustForFunc that a context passed down to a handler will be notified if the client cancels a request.

Comment: If you already have the code to call `Shutdown` when the heartbeat doesn't arrive, how is it any different than calling the cancelation func for a context?

Comment: I was hoping (under the impression) that I could get the cancellation to be called automatically so that I would not need the separate heartbeat URL.

Comment: Closing a browser alone doesn't do anything on the server. Without a request of some sort, there's no magic to notify the context that it's canceled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of sending a "heartbeat" request every so often, you could take advantage of [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Server-sent events is a web technology where the browser makes a HTTP request and keeps the connection open to receive events from the server. This could replace your need for repeated heartbeat requests by having the server shutdown when the connection to the event source is closed.

Here's a basic server implementation in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/heartbeat", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

        flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
        if !ok {
            http.Error(w, "your browser doesn't support server-sent events")
            return
        }

        // Send a comment every second to prevent connection timeout.
        for {
            _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, ": ping")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("client is gone, shutting down")
                return
            }
            flusher.Flush()
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    })
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":1323", nil))
}
```

See [using server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) for a guide on the client side.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try that.

Comment: @Ralph Do note that while this can reduce your bandwidth usage considerably (useful for mobile), this still requires you to send something over the connection every so often to prevent the connection from timing out. I'm not sure how long is the timeout though.

Comment: I can probably find that online or test it out (maybe try a couple of minutes between pings).

Answer (score 2):

Open a websocket connection from the page. On the server, exit when the websocket connection is closed:

```
func wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()

    // Shutdown on exit from handler
    defer server.Shutdown(context.Background())

    // Read  messages from client. NextReader returns an error
    // when the client shuts down.
    for {
        if _, _, err := c.NextReader(); err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
 }
```

Add this line of code to the client application:

```
 var conn = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/ws");
```

Ensure that `conn` has lifetime of the page.

This is somewhat similar to the SSE solution suggested in another answer, but has the advantage of working in more browsers.

There's no need to send a heartbeat because this is on local host.